# Laravel Parameter passing error from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to pass the parameter  $questions to view, but it gives the following error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>       Undefined variable: questions (View: C:\Users\Krishan\Documents\GitHub\GroupProject\lcurve\resources\views\quizz\questions\index.blade.php)

This is my controller index function part:

```
public function index()
{
    $questions = Question::all();    
    return view('quizz/questions.index', compact('questions'));
}
```

This is a part Of my view:

```
<tbody>
    @if (count($questions_options) > 0)
        @foreach ($questions_options as $questions_option)
            <tr data-entry-id="{{ $questions_option->id }}">
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ $questions_option->question->question_text or '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $questions_option->option }}</td>
                <td>{{ $questions_option->correct == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('quizz/questions_options.show',[$questions_option->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">View</a>-->
                    <!--<a href="{{ route('questions_options.edit',[$questions_option->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>-->
                    {!! Form::open(array(
                                        'style' => 'display: inline-block;',
                                        'method' => 'DELETE',
                                        'onsubmit' => "return confirm('".trans("quickadmin.are_you_sure")."');",
                                        'route' => ['questions_options.destroy', $questions_option->id])) !!}
                                    {!! Form::submit(trans('quickadmin.delete'), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger')) !!}
                                    {!! Form::close() !!} 
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">no_entries_in_table</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
</tbody>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCg2p.png)

Answer (score 1):

where is `questions_options` coming from? You are passing `questions`. So your for loop should be

```
@if (count($questions) > 0)
  @foreach ($questions as $question)
     //rest of your code
  @endforeach
@endif
```

and your return view part can be `return view(quizz.questions.index, compact('questions'))`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the error message you have mention should be shown. The error message should be:
`Undefined variable: questions_options (View:C:\Users\Krishan\Do........`

Because you are passing `questions` to view but you are accessing `question_options` in view. So, it should say `question_options` in undefined in view.

Besides, do you know you can avoid this count check? You can use laravel's `forelse` tag here a below:

```
@forelse($questions as $question)
     //Your table goes here
@empty
   <tr>
      <td colspan="5">no_entries_in_table</td>
   </tr>
@endforelse
```